# Nodejs handling exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application, and in some cases it can fail (my bugs or others) while processing the user's request. And in this case my application becomes completely unavailable for all users and I need to restart it. How can this issue be properly handled? For example, just log some exceptions in the error log and not break the whole process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nodemon https://github.com/remy/nodemon

It'll restart your application automatically, either upon termination due to uncaught error, or when you make changes to your code.

As for logging the exceptions and "carrying on", you'll need to actually catch the exceptions and handle them in your code.